# how to make global variable in file.properties file to use in the file

Tags: java, properties-file

I have this initially in `config.properties` file:

```
ROOTDIR=C:/testCloning
LOCALDIRWEB=C:/testCloning/web-test
LOCALDIRSERVER=C:/testCloning/server-test
```

I want to create a variable as I don't need to always repeat myself, but this is not working for me:

```
ROOTDIR=C:/testCloning
LOCALDIRWEB={ROOTDIR}/web-test
LOCALDIRSERVER={ROOTDIR}/server-test
```

Any help with this?

Comment: The java.util.Properties operate on strings only, it is a subclass of Hashtable so it's not designed to look for a value already defined.

Comment: @TavoSanchez any suggestions on how to get this implemeted?

Comment: You can extend `java.util.Properties` class and override `public String getProperty(String key)` method. And find your custom FormatElements and do the replacements.

Comment: if you are using spring, then it may help you - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties

Comment: @Md.KawserHabib not much of help to me

Comment: You can make your own implementation as pointed above, or include a third-party library like [Apache Commons Configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html)